# Difference between 2 story when talking about interior and construction in an advertisment

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **Interior** features
>
> - **2 story**
> - security features: gated community
>
> Building and construction
>
> - floor: partially carpeted
> - common walls: 2+ common walls
> - levels or stories: **2**
> - attached structure: attached

Here in this text we see the number 2 twice: first talking about the interior, second talking about construction. My question is, what is the difference? 
When it says two story interior, does it mean two floors inside one unit?

Answer (score 1):

You understand this correctly: the building has two stories, and each apartment within the building has rooms on both stories, with (presumably) a staircase joining them inside the apartment.

Answer (score 0):

The number "2" appears twice in the description to make it clear that the building is 2 stories high and that there are 2 floors inside. It is possible that a building could be 2 stories high and have 1 floor. This would be unusual for a residential building, but a commercial building, like a factory, can be more than one story high and have only one floor.